# Minitest console output does not show colors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I installed ansicon to make ansi colorized console output possible for minitest test feedback on windows.

I am running minitest with the minitest-reporters gem to format the output, yet whatever I do I can't get the output to show colors (all text is black).

Here's my test_helper.rb file:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use! Minitest::Reporters::ProgressReporter.new( { :color     => true } )

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
# Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
fixtures :all
# Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: Strange. Could you update your question with your Gemfile? And more info on your environment (Ruby version, Rails version, ...) ? Thanks

Comment: Are colors enabled in your terminal?

Comment: Have you tried passing the options via an Array  like:  Minitest::Reporters.use! [Minitest::Reporters::DefaultReporter.new(:color => true)]   The documentation at https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters  refers to the use of the options passed via an array of items.

Comment: @GrantSayer yes, I tried that already with no success

Comment: @Patrik I don't understand where I would enable that? I am on windows so ansicon should take care of it. Also, output from commands like bundle install as well as db actions are colored since installing ansicon

Comment: @NickGnd will do that as soon as I get back to the affected machine

Answer (score 5):

Reference: https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters

I see the post is from 2015. 4 years passed since then.
Anyway, let me share how it worked for me yesterday.

**My environment:**

- Ubuntu 18.04
- rails 6.0.1
- ruby 2.6.5

1) **Gemfile**:

`gem 'minitest-reporters'`

2) `bundle install`

3) **test_helper.rb**:

```
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!
```

4) `rake`

[image]

Comment: Please provide more than just code as an answer. Instead, an explanation of the code and a breakdown of why it answers the question is most beneficial.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The rest should be understood.